# File contained in compressed TAR archive missing after decompressing

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, tar, amazon-ec2

The `data.tar.xz` in [`libemu2_0.2.0+git20120122-1.2build1_amd64.deb`](http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libe/libemu/libemu2_0.2.0+git20120122-1.2build1_amd64.deb) is weird.

If I use `tar tvf`  or `tar xvf` there is a file `./usr/bin/sctest`, but after I decompressed the archive with `tar xvf`, the file `./usr/bin/sctest` is gone.

I am running `tar` on Ubuntu 18.04.6, AWS ec2. Is there a default antivirus software which removes `sctest` so that `sctest` file is missing?

Comment: [It's flagged as malware by many AVs](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/c7d56186072fd4edae28e73d1c9f4fa4f6c4956d47d9f067b791b14436d4b1bd)

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. The file `sctest` is extracted as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I executed it locally on my 18.04 machine. So can't tell if there is a VSC on EWS.

```
apt download libemu2
ar x libemu2_0.2.0+git20120122-1.2build1_amd64.deb
tar xvf data.tar.xz
#you can also try
dpkg-deb -R libemu2_0.2.0+git20120122-1.2build1_amd64.deb extracted/
```

I do not know about any default malware scanner being enabled. ClamAV is mentioned though and is available on the marketplace for bucket scanning.

ClamAV could also be installed on the instance itself. But I do not see this is enabled by default. ALso if you check the best-practice security guide of AWS EC2, they just say you should deploy a baseline instance with AV enabled (windows). They do not mention it for Linux (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-best-practices.html)